# Using foreach for sql insert from dynamic post array

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am trying to take data that is entered into a form, and use a post to process it on the same page, which will take all the data and insert it into a table in a db. This is a form that existed on an .asp page which I am trying to convert to php. The form is used for the input of Out of Stock quantities from a store.

Each row looks like this:

```
Number |        Department         | Insp Type | Qty | Memo
______________________________________________________________
1      | Bakery And Deli (OOS)     |    OOS    | 1   | george
2      | Produce                   |    OOS    | 6   | apples
```

and so on....

There are rows for ~24 departments. If a new row is added into the database, the form dynamically updates and shows the new row. The only user enterd data is Qty and Memo. The others are pre-populated by the sql query preceding the form. With the current code I have, when I echo my $sqli (insert query) this is what I get:

I also would like to return a count, for the total amount if 'items' that were input into the Qty field on the form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been trying to figured out how to do this for the past couple of days. I have been searching google left and right in an attempt to figure this out, but I can completely stumped. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you create your SQL-statement inside your foreach loop.

I would also suggest using input arrays (like `$_POST['txtStoreID'][0]` and so on...) to make things easier.

In your case, I assume the fields in your `$_POST`-array are named something like this: `txtStoreID_1`.

```
// First, create array for all results
$res_arr = array();

// Load array with all results
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    $tmp_name = explode('_',$key,2);
    $pri_key = $tmp_name[1]; // number
    $sec_key = $tmp_name[0]; // name
    if (!is_array($res_arr[$pri_key])) {
        $res_arr[$pri_key] = array();
    }
    // This creates for example: $res_arr['1']['txtStoreID'] containing 'Store_31'
    $res_arr[$pri_key][$sec_key] = $value;
}

// Next, create insert statements
foreach ($res_arr as $data) { // Now you get $data['txtStoreID'] etc.
    $sqli  = "INSERT INTO Inspection_tbl (Store_ID, Dept_ID, Quantity, Memo, User_ID, Date_Time) ";
    $sqli .= "Values ('".$data['txtStoreID']."', ";
    $sqli .= "'".$data['txtDeptID']."', ";
    $sqli .= "'".$data['txtQuantity']."', ";
    $sqli .= "'".$data['txtMemo']."', ";
    $sqli .= "'".$data['txtUserID']."', ";
    $sqli .= "'now()')";
    echo $sqli; // Check query
}
```

Do note that it's only a calculated guess regarding your input fields, though.

**Edit:**

Aside from the `is_array()` change I made, my guess is you'll need the DeptID, and not the text value for the department.

So, the bottom part of the code should be:

```
// Next, create insert statements
foreach ($res_arr as $deptID=>$data) { // Now you get $data['txtStoreID'] etc.
    $sqli  = "INSERT INTO Inspection_tbl (Store_ID, Dept_ID, Quantity, Memo, User_ID, Date_Time) ";
    $sqli .= "Values ('".$data['txtStoreID']."', ";
    $sqli .= "'".$deptID."', ";
    $sqli .= "'".$data['txtQuantity']."', ";
    $sqli .= "'".$data['txtMemo']."', ";
    $sqli .= "'".$data['txtUserID']."', ";
    $sqli .= "'now()')";
    echo $sqli; // Check query
}
```

Comment: Yeah the fields are named things such as txtStoreID_$DeptID, txtQuantity_$DeptID and so on. I commented my array portion out, and placed yours into my code instead. I placed an echo "Test 1"; echo "Test 2"; etc at each part of the code because it was not processing to the point of showing the sqli echo. It is stopping before it does the !isarray and stops. So anything below that line is not being processed. Any ideas?

Comment: Whoops, has to be `is_array()`! Didn't notice that one! Check update!

Comment: Alright, so I made the changes you suggested. It now gets to the SQL query echo. But the fields are empty. 

The SQL Query looks like this:
INSERT INTO Inspection_tbl (Store_ID, Dept_ID, Quantity, Memo, User_ID, Date_Time) Values ('', '', '', '', '', 'now()')

Comment: I am making some progress thanks to your awesome help. Still one issue though. I input data for all the fields on all the rows of the form. But I am only getting 15 of 24 rows appearing as insert queries. 

They appear in this order (form row #):
22,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,19,23,13,14,24,16,18.

I will also edit my code above, as I have added an if at the start of the sql insert query to filter out any rows that have a null qty.

Comment: With the SQL inserts in the EDIT. I used 1 for qty for row 1, qty 2 for row 2 etc. and memo1 for row 1, memo 2 for row 2, etc.

Comment: You'd have to provide a `print_r($_POST);` so we can have more information. Put that directive just before my portion of code.

Comment: Alright, I just did a print_r($_POST); before the $res_arr = array(); portion of the code you provided. It appears as though all the entered form data is there.

Comment: Okay, there's the answer! In the first `foreach`, use `$tmp_name = explode('_',$key,2);`. That should do the trick!

Comment: YOU ARE THE BEST!! That absolutely fixed the problem. I wish I had more rep, so I could up vote your answer. You have been an amazing help with this. What exactly does that extra 2 do in the explode portion?

Comment: The '2' splits the entire string in only 2 portions.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. By the way, @James, that can be arranged ;-)

Comment: I got one more question. I am trying to do a preg_replace for the qty and memo, to make sure junk doesn't get into the database. Can you check Edit 3 to see if it looks right?